# Are Settings listed in the .settings(...) of the project def are equivalent to settings in the subproject's sbt file?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am working on a big SBT project with many sub-projects (SBT ver. 0.13.17).

In the build.sbt of the *subprojects*, the dependencies are added to  libraryDependencies:

```
lazy val root = Project("subproject-name", file("."))
    .dependsOn(someOtherSubproject1)
    .dependsOn(someOtherSubproject2)


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5" % "test",
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % "3.5.3"
)
```

However, in many examples on the web I see that the dependencies are set as part of the 'settings' of the project:

```
lazy val root = Project("subproject-name", file("."))
  .dependsOn(someOtherSubproject1)
  .dependsOn(someOtherSubproject2)
  .settings(
    subprojectSettings,
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5" % "test",
      "org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % "3.5.3"
    )
  )
```

Now, this structural difference is relevant also to other settings keys (e.g. parallelExecution, scalacOptions, updateOptions etc.).

My question: what is the internal differences between the two structures? How do they affect the workings of the SBT?